# formtastic-bootstrap wont work using @import?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

Using Rails 3.2 trying twitter bootstrap and using formtastic-bootstrap with these gems as I found recommended

gem 'formtastic', git: 'git://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic.git', branch: '2.1-stable'
gem 'formtastic-bootstrap', git: 'git://github.com/cgunther/formtastic-bootstrap.git', branch: 'bootstrap2-rails3-2-formtastic-2-1'

If I require them in the manifest in application.css then they work and forms get the twitter styles however I want to override some of the colours so I know I need to use @import so I can override the $ vars.So I have put this in application.css after the manifest

@import 'twitter/bootstrap';
@import 'formtastic-bootstrap.css';

I can see these files have been got by the browser but the styles are not being applied

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! as I was upgrading a rails 3.1 app I did not see that application.css was application.css not application.css.scss! My bad! Now that sass sees the @import as its own instruction and  not a css @import it works as expected.